# How do I determine if a user exists in Desire2Learn's Learning Environment?

Tags: desire2learn

Our institution has site-wide services that integrate with the D2L Learning Environment. Occasionally a user with an account on one of our other services attempts to visit the Learning Environment before that user has a provisioned user record in the LE, and this results in an authorization error. Does the Valence Learning Framework API provide a way for me to verify that a user record exists in the LE *before* we redirect a user's session on another service to the LE's login path?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard [user query route](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html) to look for a user record in the D2L LE; using one of the `orgDefinedId` or `userName` query parameters, you can look for a user by their organization-defined ID (for example, a student number), or by their LMS user name (that they'd use to log in). For the second to work, naturally you'd need to have the practice of provisioning D2L LE users with the same user name they'd have for your institution's other services.

Notice that the "user" making the call to this route will need sufficient privileges to find the user record (and see the fields they're looking for).